# Why Javascript does not support inheritance by default?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

As from OOPS base , I always use inheritance as a powerful tool for code reuse,

Example, if I write a chess program in OOPS and when I implement a  `is-a` relationship as,

```
Class Piece{
  int teamColor;
  bool isLive;
  Positon pos;
  int Points; 
  .......
  int getTeamColor(){....}
  .......
};

Class Rook extend Piece{  //`is-a`
...... // No getTeamColor() definition here.. because the parent has the definition.
};

Class Pawn extend Piece{  //`is-a`
......// No getTeamColor() definition here.. because the parent has the definition.
};
```

I could do this with `has-a` relationship in javascript,   but the drawback I am seeing is,
I have to redefine every function in the derived class too.

Example : redefinition of getTeamColor() again in every rook,knight,pawn,king.... etc..

```
     var Pawn = function(teamColor,pos){
     var piece = new Piece(teamColor,pos);
     .......

     this.getTeamColor = function(){        
          return piece.getTeamColor();
    };
    }
```

My question is, 
Why javascript doesnot support classical inheritance as a default option?

Comment: Take a look at jOOPL (http://joopl.codeplex.com). It's a 100% JavaScript object-oriented library that enchances the language to support class-based OOP. Thus, it has inheritance and polymorphism (and many more features). I'm about to release a new version in few days with more improvements.

Comment: JavaScript supports inheritance *if you use it*. Look up "JavaScript prototype chain". As for "Why javascript does not support classical inheritance as a default option?" - because that's how JavaScript was defined. Why doesn't Java have Traits but Scala does? Why does Python support MI although Ruby does not? Why doesn't C++ have Multiple Dispatch by Dylan does? Why does Eiffel allowing break of LSP? Well, they are *different languages* and to claim one is proper - via indirect means of "classical" - is to deny that another approach is as (or more) valid.

Comment: Full article from Mozilla Developer Network about the details of javascript object model. [LINK HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model). This article covers inheritance, hierarchy and relationships while making a comparison between Java (Class-based) and Javascript (Prototype-based).

Comment: You should read Mozilla's [Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript). It covers how JavaScript handles inheritance, among other OO concepts.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Update in 2018]
JavaScript now obviously supports inheritance with native language features.

```
class A { }
class B extends A { }
```

[/Update]

JavaScript does support inheritance on a prototypal way. What you need here is not classes but the encapsulation of behavior and the ability to override.

```
function Piece() { }

Piece.prototype.color = "white";
Piece.prototype.getColor = function() { return this.color }
Piece.prototype.move = function() { throw "pure function" };

function Pawn() { }
Pawn.prototype = new Piece();    
Pawn.prototype.move = function() { alert("moved"); }
```

and now:

```
var p = new Pawn(); p.color = "black";

> p instanceof Piece
```

true

```
 p instanceof Pawn
```

true

```
p.getColor()
```

"black"

```
p.move()
```

alert...

This is the basic approach and there are many libraries out there that turn this into something that is familiar for the guys wanting  classes - so to say.

For example with JayData you can write the previous in a more encapsulated way (with the bonus of automatic constructor invocation up the chain:

```
var Piece = $data.Base.extend("Piece", {
  move: function()  {  throw "pure class" } 
});

var Pawn =  Piece.extend("Pawn", {
  move: function() { ... }
});

var p = new Pawn();
```

Comment: Thanks for your awesome answer, it helps me very well

Answer (score 8):

Because Javascript is not a [class-based object-oriented language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class-based_programming) , but rather a [prototypal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) one. It's simply a design decision.

Also, Javascript was never really "meant" for all the things we do with it today (from Node.js to ASM.js). The fact that it's still relevant is a testament Brendan Eich and Co. So you may wonder why X or Y was never implemented in JS, but the fact of the matter is that we use JS for things that 20 years ago would have been unforeseeable.

Answer (score 1):

Many good books on various traditional OO languages (including Java, C# and C++) specifically advise against using "implementation inheritance" where possible. Example: Effective Java by Joshua Bloch.

The strange fact is that although implementation inheritance seems to give a regular "shape" to your code, it isn't really helping you solve a problem; more often, it causes problems in the long run.

Those authors tend to give their blessing instead to "interface inheritance" - but in a duck-typed language such as JavaScript there is no need to explicitly declare such inheritance.

And in JS you can "reuse" the same function by simply assigning it as a property on multiple objects. Whatever flavour of inheritance you need, you can conjure it up out of nothing.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript does not even have real OOP-style classes, you're just able to simulate something similar.

In your example, you can achieve inheritance by doing

```
var Pawn = function(teamColor, pos) {
    Piece.call(this, teamColor, pos);
}
```

However, you should typically attach methods to the functions prototype rather than to any new created object. In that case, you can simulate inheritance by setting up a prototype chain, e.g., like CoffeeScript does it:

```
var a, b, _ref,
  __hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty,
  __extends = function(child, parent) { for (var key in parent) { if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; } function ctor() { this.constructor = child; } ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; child.prototype = new ctor(); child.__super__ = parent.prototype; return child; };

a = (function() {
  function a() {}

  return a;

})();

b = (function(_super) {
  __extends(b, _super);

  function b() {
    _ref = b.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    return _ref;
  }

  return b;

})(a);
```

Comment: this is imho overkill (and a bit gibberish) for the tasks required: overriding behavior down the class tree.

Answer (score 0):

The following code block will "extend" one JavaScript prototype from the other, and ensure that the "instanceof" operator works correctly for the base and derived classes.

From what I can tell, setting TestB's prototype to a new TestA allows for the logical consistancy of the "instanceof" operator.

Passing this to TestA gives the new instance all the desired properties and methods.

Doing it this way is a sort of balance between stylistic desires and pragmatic ones. This will work in most any browser, even Internet Explorer if you're forced to support it. It also helps because having the methods contained in the same block "feels" a lot like your traditional OO syntax.

Also, the main reason JavaScript doesn't support the traditional style of OO is because of its founding philosophy. The founding philosophy is freedom. This freedom is intended to allow developers to engineer their own styles to fit the project's needs.

```
function TestA(){
  var me = this;

  me.method = function(){
  }
}

function TestB(){
  TestA.call(this);
  var me = this;

  me.otherMethod = function(){
  }
}
TestB.prototype = new TestA();

var test = new TestB();

console.log(test);

console.log(test instanceof TestB);
console.log(test instanceof TestA);

//TestA { method: [Function], otherMethod: [Function] }
//true
//true
```